# fillna with last non nan value based on a condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

i have a pandas dataframe with the following columns

```
         open        high         low       close
0    66069.69    66151.73    65932.01    65998.30   
1    65998.29    65998.30    65702.43    65836.37   
2    65836.38    66000.00    65814.63    65924.44   
3    65924.43    66065.78    65864.82    66021.54   
4    66021.55    66084.32    65800.00    65801.19   
5    65805.00    65886.41    65750.00    65797.19
```

would like to create two new columns using the logic

```
if open<close:
    +HL = (high-low)
    -HL = the last  -HL value if it exist else nan
else:
    +HL = the last +HL value if it exist else nan
    -HL = (high-low)
```

the new df should look like this.

```
         open        high         low       close      +HL       -HL
0    66069.69    66151.73    65932.01    65998.30      nan    219.72
1    65998.29    65998.30    65702.43    65836.37      nan    295.87
2    65836.38    66000.00    65814.63    65924.44   185.37    295.87
3    65924.43    66065.78    65864.82    66021.54   200.96    295.87
4    66021.55    66084.32    65800.00    65801.19   200.96    284.32
5    65805.00    65886.41    65750.00    65797.19   200.96    136.41
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just assign `high - low` to the two different columns based on opposite conditions and then forward-fill:

```
df['+HL'] = np.where(df['open'] < df['close'], df['high'] - df['low'], np.nan)
df['-HL'] = np.where(df['open'] >= df['close'], df['high'] - df['low'], np.nan)
df = df.ffill()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
       open      high       low     close     +HL     -HL
0  66069.69  66151.73  65932.01  65998.30     NaN  219.72
1  65998.29  65998.30  65702.43  65836.37     NaN  295.87
2  65836.38  66000.00  65814.63  65924.44  185.37  295.87
3  65924.43  66065.78  65864.82  66021.54  200.96  295.87
4  66021.55  66084.32  65800.00  65801.19  200.96  284.32
5  65805.00  65886.41  65750.00  65797.19  200.96  136.41
```